# Replacement values of a column in a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame `mat`. I would like to create data frame `res`, means that If the second column is 1, replace correspond first column value instead, and if it is 0, replace it with Inf. How can I do this in R?

```
      c1 = c(10, 1, 3, 4, 6, 8)
      c2 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
      mat = data.frame(c1=c1, c2=c2)
      > mat
        c1 c2
      1 10  1
      2  1  1
      3  3  0
      4  4  1
      5  6  0
      6  8  1

     > c2 = c(10, 1, Inf, 4, Inf, 8)
     > res = data.frame(c1=c1, c2=c2)
     > res
       c1  c2
     1 10  10
     2  1   1
     3  3 Inf
     4  4   4
     5  6 Inf
     6  8   8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ifelse` and try this:

```
> (res <- transform(mat, c2=ifelse(c2==1, c1, Inf)) )
  c1  c2
1 10  10
2  1   1
3  3 Inf
4  4   4
5  6 Inf
6  8   8
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
res <- mat
res[res$c2 == 1,]$c2 <- res[res$c2 == 1,1]
res[res$c2 == 0,]$c2 <- Inf
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy and efficient with a simple division:

```
transform(mat, c2 = c1 / c2)

  c1  c2
1 10  10
2  1   1
3  3 Inf
4  4   4
5  6 Inf
6  8   8
```